# Why do we use bamboo as סכך?

Tags: halacha, schach

Why do we utilize bamboo as סכך?

Comment: Welcome! There's no way to PM users on this site. Please take our [tour] to learn more about how this site is different from some others; among other things, questions are easily accessible for a long time and often get good-quality answers late.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Goldie! Consider reading this Beginners Guide to the site: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I don't think the op is asking why bamboo is kosher, i think the op is asking why do so many people use bamboo specifically. I could be wrong, but that's what it seems like.

Comment: @user613 its only pointless if you know its pointless. Many people come here seeking questions to things that are sometimes pointless and sometimes not. Imagine someone asking why taleissim are white. Imagine them asking why taleissim have those little knots along the side. One has a halachic reason behind it and one is really pointless. How should an uninformed observer know the difference without asking?

Comment: @Monica Cellio. The second question is about tikra, this question is general mah zot. It need an other answer I vote to in duplication. Because the answer must be different

Comment: @user6591 that's a good point.  I've reopened.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's still a completely abysmal post.

Comment: @DoubleAA if it should be closed for a different reason, go for it.  I was just undoing my erroneous dupe.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of practicality. See the [Wikipedia entry on bamboo.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo)

> Bamboos include some of the fastest-growing plants in the world... 
>   Certain species of bamboo can grow 91 cm (3 ft) within a 24-hour period, at a rate of almost 4 cm (1.5 in) an hour (a growth around 1 mm every 90 seconds, or one inch every 40 minutes)...
>   Bamboo has a higher specific compressive strength than wood, brick, or concrete and a specific tensile strength that rivals steel.

All this adds up to a profitable long lasting product that fits the bill for schach, having grown from the ground and is now detatched.

Answer (score 1):

Mishna Succa1, 4:

> זה הכלל, כל שהוא מקבל טמאה ואין גדולו מן הארץ, אין מסככין בו. וכל דבר שאינו מקבל טמאה וגדולו מן הארץ, מסככין בו. ‏
>
> That is the rule, everything which can become uncleaned and didn't growing from earth, we don't cover with him; everything which doesn't can become uncleaned and did growing from earth, we do cover with him.

Bartenura:

> כל דבר שאינו כו' - לאפוקי כלי עץ ובגדי פשתן ומחצלאות, שאע"פ שגדוליהם מן הארץ אין מסככין בהן הואיל ומקבלין טומאה: ‏
>
> וגידוליו מן הארץ וכו' - דכתיב חג הסוכות [תעשה לך באספך] מגרנך ומיקבך, בפסולת גרן ויקב הכתוב מדבר, כלומר מן הנשאר אחר שאספת הגורן והיקב כגון קשין וזמורות מהם עשה סוכה : ‏
>
> Wood and linen skills despite of their come from earth,are not regular because they can become uncleaned.
>
> We learn the criterion from the verse which says that you need to make a succa at the season of wheat and grape harvest and. This is considered as an allusion that you need to build the succa with the residues of the harvest, as strew and twigs

Practically Bamboo is very strong an will not be deteriorated by sun and rain until the end of the week of Succot.